# Full Screen Video behind bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video

I have a layout which uses bootstrap 3. Something like the code below. I want to create the effect of a video background behind the container. As shown in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mpq32dy/3/). However, for some reason, the video is appearing in front of the text, despite my having set the `z-index` such that this should happen. What should I change to get the video to sit in the background? You can see it if you resize the video, so that the text appears above it.

```
<div class="homepage-hero-module fullheight">
    <div class="video-container">
        <div class="title-container">
            <div class="headline">
                <h1>Welcome to our Company</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <div class="inner">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
            <source src="http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/dock.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.</video>
        <div class="poster hidden">
            <img src="http://www.videojs.com/img/poster.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

## EDIT:

Not sure why, but on my small PC, the video on the JSFIddle doesn't show, I just get white text on black background, whereas on my big imac, I get the video over the top of the text.

Comment: You should add the relevant CSS, and also providing a working example using JSFiddle or Embeded SO Code snippet to show the issue.

Comment: @Zeratops There is a link to a JSfiddle in the question, showing the issue. Didn't include the css as there is quite a lot and it is on the JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code that I have used for video background.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <video autoplay loop poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
        <source src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <object>
            <embed src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" />
        </object>  
    </video>
    <div>
    <h4>Content</h4>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url('//demosthenes.info/assets/images/polina.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-transition: 1s opacity;
    -o-transition: 1s opacity;
    -webkit-transition: 1s opacity;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}

h4{
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
}
```

Working fiddle:

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mpq32dy/2/)

The text is showing properly so I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Not quite what I am after, as I want the video to fit behind a bootstrap `container-fluid` and to have content below, so you can scroll past the home page. Don't really understand what is wrong with my code?